# How to make Robots.txt and Sitemap.xml only accessable through search engine bots

Tags: stack-overflow, robots.txt, googlebot, google-crawlers, xml-sitemap

Several website like Quora, Stackechange, and including Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml) only access through the search engine crawlers (Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc).

1. How can i do same for my website robots.txt and sitemap.xml
2. What are the user-agents these crawlers use and where i can find a list
3. Google and Bing crawlers do not use any static IP's, they are dynamic and lot of IP's. How this big site like Stackoverflow manage whitelisting IP's of crawlers.
4. How big site content indexed instantly on Google. like my this question will get indexed instantly after publishing it. where my website usually take 2-7 days for indexing.